# in wpf how to ensure i get selected index for a combobox even if selection is not changed

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I am developing a module where i want to know which item is selected by user in combobox, 
I am using SelectionChanged event of ComboBox but it doesn't fire if i don't change selection to another item in list,
so in short which event i should use so as to get current selection of user though he may or may not change the selection

Thanks in advance

Comment: As long as the user doesn't interact with the ComboBox, no event will be fired. You can however always get the value of the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx) or [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) properties.

Comment: say 1st default is '1' but i selected '2' and i just click but don't change it's selection, event will not fire any additional event than selectionChanged??? i am newbie in wpf

Comment: How about [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown.aspx) or [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseup.aspx)?

Comment: no you don't get notfied @Clemens

Comment: Then try `PreviewMouseDown` or `PreviewMouseUp`.

Comment: after lots of hit and trials i got it,,,, i should add PreviewMouseUp for each comboBoxItems and catch it !!!!...... thanks for giving direction @Clemens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is:
add PreviewMouseUp handler to each of comboBoxItem so if user changes selection / he doesn't change means again select the same item still you will get notified thanks @Clemens for guiding ....